# Delete incoming SMS in android marshmallow 6.0?

Tags: android, sms, android-6.0-marshmallow

How to delete incoming sms in android marshmallow?. i tried but as of my knowledge above kitkat we could not delete the inbox sms. if we need to delete inbox sms  should make the app as default. my question is whatsapp deleting their sms once verification has done,how they doing the same and is possible to delete incoming sms without make my app as default?. sorry for my bad english.

```
    public void deleteSMS(Context context, long messageId) {
    try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id"}, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);

                if (id == messageId) {
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                    Log.e("Message:", "Message is Deleted successfully");
                }

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean by default the system permission and show what you tried

Comment: "whatsapp deleting their sms once verification has done" - I don't believe that's true. Not on any Android version since 4.4, anyway.

Comment: i posted my code.please check it @zombie..

Comment: then how they deleting their OTP? @MikeM.

Comment: I'm saying, they don't. In fact, I just installed WhatsApp to test, and it does no such thing. The SMS message is still sitting in my inbox.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate. If you can provide concrete proof that WhatsApp is doing what you claim on an Android version > 4.4, let me know, and I'll reopen it.